# UIButton disappears after succesfull build

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

I am facing problem with my new app. I have developed many apps, but this problem i have for the first time. For testing my app I am using Apple iPad Mini 4. 
I have a new, empty project. I have added only one UIButton. But when I build this project, succesfull build, and the app is running, after 2 seconds the UIButton disappears. When I use iPad or iPhone simulator, the button is there forever. No error appears, so i really do not know, what is going on. Anybody with similar problem?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func example(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Hello")
}  

}
```

Comment: Show some code pls

Comment: Did you give right constraint to button for iPad?

Comment: Yes I have the right constraint. I can see the button but after 2 second it disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the same thing but working fine....no issues.
What you are saying is not possible It's not possible that way.

It's only possible if you put your button somewhere in LaunchScreen.
If you put you button on launch screen you can still add action to ViewController but you can't add outlet.

Verify this thing and let me know.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that this think shouldnt be possible, because of that I am asking. I have it in Main.storyboard, I have checked it now.

Comment: My apologize, I have bug in Xcode, but after restart it shows me the right options in LaunchScreen and Main.storyboard and it was really in LaunchScreen, what a stupid mistake.